# reading multiple files from multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I want to read files one after another in strict order.After reading a portion from one file  , the associated thread will sleep and another will start , this will go till all the lines from all the files complete printing.  What is the best possible way.

Comment: From what you are saying, best solution is to not use threads

Comment: let's suppose i want to use thread. Just for the sake of learning it. Then how to do this. Like stopping one thread after reading one line , and then starting another reading a line , and so on. Hope this makes some sense.

Comment: If you want to use threads, solve a problem which needs it, else you are learning it wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

Making threads to sleep is a very bad practice. According to your explanation you do not need several threads here. You can read first file until you see specific pattern. The read a portion of second file etc. Why do you need threads here?

Threads are useful if you want to perform at least 2 task in parallel. Sequential work can and should be implemented using one thread.

Comment: Lets suppose i am breaking at each line of my File. So I want to write the second line of each file in the second go one by one , using the same threads which were associated with each of the file.
 Let the files be F1,F2,F3,F4,F5. And Threads will be T1 for reading F1, T2 for reading F2, T3 for reading F3, T4 for reading F4, T5 for reading F5.
Now the  output looks like  F1 first line 
F2 first line
F3 first line
F4 first line
F5 first line
F1 second Line
F2 second Line
F3 second Line
F4 second Line
F5 second Line
..